# Android : Two SMS are sent at a time

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am facing a very strange issue. I am sending sms from my app using intent. But, two sms are sent at a time and user is charged for two. I had checked for any duplicates in my project but found nothing. I had gone some queries posted here related to same issue but they didn't helped me. Below, is my code to send sms:

```
String mMailSubject = "iTithe Android App";
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Log.e("ITITHE SMS INTENT", "KITKAT");
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms
                .getDefaultSmsPackage(MoreActivity.this);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mMailSubject + "\n" + msg);

        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
            sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("ITITHE SMS INTENT", "OTHER PLATFORM");
        sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", mMailSubject + "\n" + msg);
    }
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: what do u want to do?????

Comment: Maybe it is the calling code that is calling this twice?

Comment: @AnilBhatiya He wants to send only one SMS at a time. Nitish what SIM provider you are using ?

Comment: @AnilBhatiya I would have thought it is pretty obvious what he wants to do.

Comment: How long is your message text?

Comment: Your message is exceeding 160 char..

Comment: @FunLove You mean that sms is sent in two parts?

Comment: @Kedarnath Mine is Idea, but this app is for an US client and he is also facing same issue

Comment: @AnilBhatiya I want to send only one sms at a time

Comment: Check for the message size(it should not exceed 160 to meet your requirement) else paste complete code or check for calling code twice

Comment: @Nitish, how you are calling this code ?

Comment: @Kedarnath on a button click in dialog. I got the issue. The length of message has exceeded 160 characters, so the message is sent twice. I'll update this in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with code but with the length of message. The message length exceeded 160 characters so the SMS was sent in two parts.